# Visual Studio web project debug mode doesn't end automatically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

In a WPF or WinForms application, when you press F5 (or click the green arrow), it opens the application in debug mode. Then when you close the application, it stops debug mode (and you can click the green arrow on the toolbar or press F5 again).

But, for me anyways, on any web application (ASP.NET, MVC, etc...) that runs in a browser, when I close the browser window, Visual Studio remains in debug mode (F5 does nothing, and the green arrow is disabled). Its such a minor thing that I've put up with it for a few months... but its really starting to get on my nerves. **How can I solve this?**

If it makes any difference, I use the Dev version of Chrome, and Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

**EDIT**

For clarification, I already know how to end Debug mode. I just want it to end automatically when I close my browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F5 will enable debug mode, but Shift + F5 is used to exit debug mode.

Comment: I know how to exit debug mode, but I want it to do it automatically when I close the browser window.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. As far as I'm aware, this cannot be done with Google Chrome. It should work fine with Internet Explorer and Firefox, even if you just close the tab and not the window. The logic given is that they create separate processes for each window/tab, so closing one will terminate the process and signal VS to stop debugging. As I understand, Chrome also creates separate processes, so maybe VS can't recognize that the process has terminated or something. Not sure there, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're having the same issue I was having but if you manually set the "Start External Program:" under your project properties to the browser you want to use, even if it is your default, and make sure you have the localhost:Port# in the field below, it should fix your problem.

I was debugging just fine before upgrading Windows 7 32-bit to 64-bit (Visual Studio 2010 would exit debugging mode upon closing Firefox). After reinstalling everything, Visual Studio wouldn't exit debug-mode and I spent at least an hour trying to figure out why, thinking it had something to do with my IIS config or the settings in Firefox.

What happened is previously I had Chrome as my default browser, and after the upgrade I decided to use Firefox as my default. So instead of filling in the "Start external program" I just was selecting the "Specific Page:" to have it startup my default browser. But apparently Visual Studio won't attach to the process this way. Hope this helps, if not you then someone.  :)

Comment: I tried this - start external program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" and Command line arguments "http://localhost:51491/". VS opened the browser correctly, but did NOT enter debug mode.